# Since $C\ne(C∪(A∪B)),$ how does $C−R = (C∪(A∪B))−R?$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This question is from a course, *Introduction to Probability, Statistics and Random Processes*:

> Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be three events in the sample space $S$.
> Suppose we know that
> $A∪B∪C=S$,
> $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$,
> $P(B)=\frac{2}{3}$,
> $P(A∪B)=\frac{5}{6}.$ Find $P(C−(A∪B))$.

The given solution:

> We can write $C−(A∪B) = (C∪(A∪B))−(A∪B)$
>
> Which then becomes "$S−(A∪B)$" and finally "$(A∪B)^\text{c}$".

How does $C$ become ($C∪(A∪B))$?

Comment: Probability cannot be greater than 1. Do you mean 0.12, 0.23, 0.56?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site. I see that someone fixed the formatting of your previous question for you. Please don't rely on people doing that in the future.

Comment: $X-Y = (X\cup Y) - Y$ but $X\neq Y$... This is because, if you remove all elements of $Y$ from either $X$ or $X\cup Y$, it's the same set only...

Comment: Ughhhh...just cancel $R$ on both sides

Answer (score 0):

> > We can write $C−(A∪B) = (C∪(A∪B))−(A∪B)\tag1$
>
> How does $C$ become ($C∪(A∪B))$?

Good question! In general, for sets, $$P-R=Q-R \kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies P=Q;$$ for example, $$\{1,2,3,4\}-\{3,4,5,6\}=\{1,2\}=\{1,2\}-\{3,4,5,6\}.$$

**Explanation**

Note that set subtraction $$X-Y$$ (also written $X{\setminus}Y$), by definition, means $$X\cap Y^\complement;$$ as such, the analogous "set addition" operation $$X+Y$$ should be understood as a shorthand for $$X\cup Y.$$ Therefore, in the following sequence of steps, line $(3)$ is an **erroneous conclusion** from lines $(1)$ & $(2):$ $$C−(A∪B) = (C∪(A∪B))−(A∪B)\tag1$$
$$C−(A∪B)+(A∪B) = (C∪(A∪B))−(A∪B)+(A∪B)\tag2$$
$$\color\red{\therefore\quad C = (C∪(A∪B))}.\tag3$$